# Angular - $routeParams.itemID for loading domain.com/:itemID ALMOST WORKING?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, mongoose

I am looking to have parameters in the route, by using a colon before the variable name

```
// dynamic pages for each ITEM, once selected
// from $routeParams.itemID in ItemCtrl
.when('/:itemID', {
        templateUrl: 'views/item.html',
        controller: 'ItemController'
})
```

When a div-box is clicked, Angular should route to the specific item

```
<div class="itemBox" ng-click="getItem(item._id)">
```

Right now, the call to the node/express API seems to be working

```
[16:36:18.108] GET http://localhost:8080/api/items/534240001d3066cc11000002 [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 4ms]
```

**But this error logs in the console:**

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    ...
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/Users/Username/Downloads/project/v19/app/routes.js:41:8)
    ...
```

Line 41 (for 41:8?) in routes.js is res.json(item);

```
// load the item model
var Item = require('./models/item');

// get One item
app.get('/api/items/:item_id', function(req, res) {

        // use mongoose to get the one item from the database
        Item.findById({
                _id : req.params.item_id
        },

        function(err, item) {

                // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
                if (err)
                        res.send(err)

                res.json(item); // return the item in JSON format
        });
});
```

Though it seems like the issue might be in the Controller because all of the other API calls work.. And so I tried passing $routeParams all over the place!

```
angular.module('ItemCtrl', [])

// inject the Item service.factory into our controller
.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $routeParams, $http, Items, isEmptyObjectFilter) {

        // get an Item after clicking it
        $scope.getItem = function(id, $routeParams) {
                Items.getOne(id, $routeParams)
                        // if successful getByID, call our function to get the Item data
                        .success(function(data, $routeParams) {
                                // assign our Item
                                $scope.item = data;
                                // for use with a parameter in appRoutes.js using itemID as the variable
                                $scope.itemID = $routeParams.itemID;
                        })
                        .error(function(data) {
                                console.log('Error: ' + data);
                        });
        };
});
```

Or maybe it's the service? Does this need to pass $routeParams as function(id, $routeParams)

```
angular.module('ItemService', [])

// super simple service
// each function returns a promise object 
.factory('Items', function($http) {
        return {
                get : function() {
                        return $http.get('/api/items');
                },
                getOne : function(id) {
                        return $http.get('/api/items/' + id);
                },
                create : function(itemData) {
                        return $http.post('/api/items', itemData);
                },
                delete : function(id) {
                        return $http.delete('/api/items/' + id);
                }
        }
});
```

Would really appreciate some assistance debugging this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are getting the data correctly. The problem is that you want the route to change after successfully getting the API call?

$routeParams won't change the route for you. That just gets the data. Use $location to change the route.

```
.controller('ItemController', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Items, isEmptyObjectFilter) {
$scope.getItem = function(id) {
    Items.getOne(id)
        .success(function(data) {
              $scope.item = data;
              $scope.itemID = $routeParams.itemID;

              // redirect
              $location.path('/' + $routeParams.itemID);
        });
});
});
```

Since all of your data seems to be ready to go, you just need Angular to redirect to the route. $location should be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for this.. Almost there.. It redirects to the item.html page, but then the console is reporting another GET /api/items after GET /api/items/534240001d3066cc11000002.. Any ideas why it would be performing another GetAll?

Comment: Do you have a main controller that performs a get all when the page is hit? Or is there anything else in the ItemController that could be doing it?

Since you are calling the ItemController again when the route changes, anything in there would get run again.

Comment: Ah, got it.. There's a general get in there too.. Will separate the ctrls.. Thanks again!

Comment: Sweet! Glad I could help.

Comment: Uhh, turns out something is up with the data too.. Have been testing all sorts of stuff, but the item.html is not being populated with the angular bindings because the data returned is [object Object] with this message: `"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id""` Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you console.log the data on both the Node and Angular sides? Do you get it back on both sides? Maybe it is on the Node side or in the Angular service.

Comment: On the node side, console.log(emotion) after the res.json(item) logs undefined, and the url is localhost:8080/undefined

Comment: In node, you don't need to have the app.get be with the param. Change **app.get('/api/items/:item_id'** to **app.get('/api/items')**. The param is passed through the **req**. Also in the Angular service you need to pass it as data, not as a url part. So change **return $http.get('/api/items/' + id)** to **$http.get('/api/items', id)**. Make it similar to how you handle the create in your Angular service.

Answer (score 1):

That message is because you are getting an error and executing the res.send() method, and after that you have res.json(), express is trying to respond twice.

Try changing:

```
if (err)
  res.send(err)
```

To:

```
if (err) {
  res.json({ error: err }); 
} else {
  var object = item.toObject();
  res.json(object);
}
```

**Angular resource example:**

```
angular.module('ItemService')
.factory('Items', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/items/:itemID', {
        itemID: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}]);
```

Now you can do this in your controller:

```
// Find
Items.get({
  itemID: $routeParams.itemID
}, function(item) {
  $scope.item = item;
});

// Update
$scope.item.name = 'New name';
$scope.item.$update();

// Remove
$scope.item.$remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, no error anymore.. But it doesn't route to the /:itemID - is that because of where $routeParams is passed in the Ctrl, or do I need res.json(item); somewhere still?

Comment: You have to use angular resources instead of $http requests

Comment: Not quite sure what that entails.. Do you have an example?

Comment: Yeah, I've modified my answer